# POP client issue during AUTH state

Tags: c, openssl, pop3

Hello I am writing a POP3 client in C on Ubuntu. I am using OpenSSL.
I am stuck in the AUTHORIZATION state! I send the user name and get a success response,
and when i send the password , it always says `-ERR bad command`. I am sure the password is correct. Since i am using OpenSSL , Wireshark was not of much help. Here's how I am sending the password

```
scanf("%s",password);
sprintf(pass_cmd,"PASS %s\r\n",password);
sent =  SSL_write(ssl, pass_cmd, strlen(pass_cmd));
```

`pass_cmd` is flushed and cleaned before used in write.The `strlen` is also giving a valid size including `\r\n`

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: So, did you test the answer? If so please accept, upvote, downvote or comment it, so that others may know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Reading RFC 1939 and 1734, you can see that POP has several authentication mechanisms and a given server does not always accept PASS (they may require APOP, for instance). It seems it is the case with Gmail, for instance.

Try with another POP server or change the settings of your own server.